# Git files needs merge, but not present

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I am tryinng to merge update from a master code on another person's github page, and I have almost everything fixed. Now when I type `git checkout master` I get this in response:

```
$ git checkout master
> FtcRobotController/src/main/java/com/qualcomm/ftcrobotcontroller/opmodes/NullOp.java: needs merge
> doc/javadoc/com/qualcomm/robotcore/hardware/DcMotor.MotorCallback.html: needs merge
> error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

When I run `git diff` I get this:

```
> Unmerged path FtcRobotController/src/main/java/com/qualcomm/ftcrobotcontroller/opmodes/NullOp.java
> Unmerged path doc/javadoc/com/qualcomm/robotcore/hardware/DcMotor.MotorCallback.html
```

Now these two files do not appear when I look through my file manager.

Git newbie, please be kind to me.

Comment: The first question here is *what are you merging, and why?* Your question says "... update from a master code on another person's github page" but you cannot merge from a web page, you can only merge from a *commit* (often, the tip of some named remote-tracking branch, such as `origin/master` or `upstream/develop`). If your Git is not too ancient, `git status` output may be helpful as well.

Comment: @torek my bad. I have created a pull request and checkedout a new branch where I resolved the merges.

Comment: OK, so, you ... used the GitHub "fork a repo" interface?  I don't normally work with any of this myself, but just as a general rule, it will help those who do, to list specifically what tools (GitHub's "desktop" thing?) you used and what commands you've run / things you've clicked in some GUI / ...

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a duplicate of [Git merge errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006737/git-merge-errors) and [How to resolve a git merge conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171076/how-to-resolve-a-git-merge-conflict)

(first couple of results from a google search for 'error: you need to resolve your current index first git')

Basically, you are in the middle of a merge and need to finish or reset the merge before doing anything else.

Comment: The second one of those does not solve my problem, and the first one recommends resetting the entire thing, I do not want to reset, especially as those files were not there either.

Comment: In addition, it recommends simply merging them, but the issue is that I cannot merge this part, because the files are missing.