# GIT corrupt files (<<<<<<<<HEAD)

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have this in my files after some trouble with VS2012 git-plugin:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
<<<<<<< HEAD
using NHibernate;
=======
>>>>>>> dd2c3d7dfe81074e7c5a73f8e4ca2584481a74f1

namespace Controll.Hosting.Tests
{
[TestClass]
public class TestBase
{
<<<<<<< HEAD
    protected ISessionFactory SessionFactory;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTestBase()
    {
            SessionFactory = NHibernateHelper.GetSessionFactoryForMockedData();
=======
    [ClassInitialize]
    public void InitializeTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Settings NHibernateHelper.IsInTesting -> True");
        NHibernateHelper.IsInTesting = true;
>>>>>>> dd2c3d7dfe81074e7c5a73f8e4ca2584481a74f1
        }
    }
}
```

How can i reset my files?

Comment: Those are merge conflicts. Files are not corrupted.

Comment: I see, can i force git overwrite everything with the new changes?

Comment: You have to decide and keep data you want. GIT will only point out the conflicts. Modify that code according to answer given below and save the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git merge left marks in my files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657315/git-merge-left-marks-in-my-files)

Comment: @vedarthk: When this makes scripts nonfunctional, or when it happens to data files, or logs — I venture to say, for any file type — then yes, the merge conflicts have corrupted the files. Sure, the files can be recovered, but if they are made to be a non-functional state, I call them corrupted.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you had wasn't **trouble** but **conflicts**. This happens when the files are modified by two different persons at the same place (you both add/remove/modify things inside the same lines).

You can simply update your files manually, by deciding to keep everything between `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `=======`, or between `=======` and `>>>>>>>`, or some mix of the two. Once you *resolve* all your *conflicts*, you just need to commit your changes.

To discard local changes on a file, you can do

```
git checkout yourfile
```

or, for all files using

```
git checkout -- .
```

You can also decide, for each file, if you want to keep your version or the repository version with

```
git checkout --ours yourfile # Your version
git checkout --theirs yourfile # Repository version
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will accept this, but can i chose to keep all my local changes (im moving back to a really old repo and many files are affected)?

Comment: @ErikTJ You shouldn't decide to do something on *all* files. The best thing, even if it's a bit annoying, is to look at each file and decide according to what git points out as conflicts.

Answer (score 8):

Your Q is answered best by alestanis, already. Still for easy lookup:

An explanation of those conflict markers `>>>>>` ... `<<<<<` can be found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10657315/923794).

There's more info about merging at [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5772908/923794).

And `git help merge` is quite explicitly helpful as well:

> HOW TO RESOLVE CONFLICTS
>
> After seeing a conflict, you can do two things:
>
> ·   Decide not
>   to merge. The only clean-ups you need are to reset the index file to
>   the HEAD commit to reverse 2. and to clean up working
>          tree changes made by 2. and 3.; `git merge --abort` can be used for this.
>
> ·   Resolve the conflicts. Git will mark the conflicts in
>   the working tree. Edit the files into shape and `git add` them to the
>   index. Use
>          `git commit` to seal the deal.
>
> You can work through the conflict with a number of tools:
>
> · Use a mergetool.  `git mergetool` to launch a graphical mergetool which
>   will work you through the merge.
>
> ·   Look at the diffs.  `git diff`
>   will show a three-way diff, highlighting changes from both the HEAD
>   and MERGE_HEAD versions.
>
> ·   Look at the diffs from each branch. 
>   `git log --merge -p <path>` will show diffs first for the HEAD version
>   and then the MERGE_HEAD
>          version.
>
> ·   Look at the originals.  `git show :1:filename` shows the common ancestor, `git show :2:filename` shows the HEAD version, and `git show :3:filename` shows the MERGE_HEAD version.

Answer (score 0):

Using SourceTree for git to manage my builds with Kdiff installed has helped me resolve 99% of these issues really efficiently.

I'm just left with trying to remove these from my SOU file in .Net, usually replacing the SOU file with an older version resolves this.