# GitHub putting junk in my code?

Tags: android, eclipse, github

I opened my Android app code today (which is stored on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)), and I noticed a bunch of generated junk that looks like this:

```
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
<<<<<<< HEAD
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
=======
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
>>>>>>> 644f9ed0b1244dfd51590ba98bcd9dcf8f9c89e4
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

How did that get there? Was it Eclipse? GitHub? How can I prevent this?

Comment: You have missed some `merge` messages when you pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not junk and has been done by GIT. You would have done some merging of the code and there might have been conflicts. Those are merge conflicts. See the explanation here: [GIT corrupt files (<<<<<<<<HEAD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291056/git-corrupt-files-head) . You can also resolve then manually.