# How to make git to save different versions of a conflicted file into the workspace

Tags: git, conflict, git-merge, tortoisegit, git-config

In SVN if there is a conflict, the different versions of the conflicted file are saved to the workspace with postfixes. Can I have this in Git as well? I should now hold some training about TortoiseGit, and if a binary conflict occurs, I don't see any simple option to have the different versions of the file in the workspace. I know that I can checkout the file from a specific hash with a different name, but I want it automatically.

So what I want in my workspace **automatically saved** in case of a conflict:

- myconflictedfile.doc
- myconflictedfile.doc.base
- myconflictedfile.doc.theirs
- myconflictedfile.doc.mine

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

In case of a merge conflict, git already save those different version for you:
From [`git help merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> Look at the originals:
>
> - **`git show :1:filename`** shows the common ancestor,
> - **`git show :2:filename`** shows the `HEAD` version, and
> - **`git show :3:filename`** shows the `MERGE_HEAD` version.

You can also quickly resolve a conflict merge by [choosing 'mine' or 'their' version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15291122/6309).

```
git checkout --ours   yourfile # Your version
git checkout --theirs yourfile # Repository version
```

Comment: Thanks VonC. Do you have any idea, how to get the files with TortoiseGit during a rebase for example? I cannot find any "non command line" solution for this.

Comment: @GáborLipták no, I didn't see a way to do this through the GUI. You can setup a mergetool, though, which will show you in case of conflict the 4 files (merged, base, outs, theirs), as at the end of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309, with setup mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/586002/6309.